# Difference between throw and throws in finally

Tags: java

I am preparing for **OCP** exam and I'm using **Enthuware**. 
I got this question, what is the result of compiling and running the following code?

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Obviously, the code does compile but it throws a `RuntimeException` and I totally understand why.
I'm just curious why the following code doesn't compile:

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    test();
}
```

Where `test()` function looks like:

```
static final void test() throws RuntimeException {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Even though I declared `test` function as `final` because I thought that it might the compiler is aware of **overriding** ...

Could someone please explain it to me?

Sorry for bad English!

-- **Edit:**
Just wondering why down-vote?

Error message is compile error:

> Unhandled exception type IOException

And the error message when I tried to compile it is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: And whats the error message?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No. `RuntimeException` does not need to be catched nor declared to be thrown.

Comment: Works for me.... (and throws a RuntimeException)

Comment: @Niroda - It works for me too. [DEMO](https://ideone.com/MMAlYR) - As you can see, stderr says *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException at Main.java:21*

Comment: It's compile error and it actually complains about `catch` statement because I'm re-throwing the checked exception!
I will try to upload an image :)

Comment: @Niroda Paste the error in the question along with the real code. No images of code/stack trace, please

Comment: I edited it and added the error message :)

Comment: @BackSlash No! in the first one if you use `throw new RuntimeException()` in finally block the code compiles without any issue but it throws an exception at runtime, but the second one doesn't compile at all!

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet compiles because the `finally` block runs *before* a value is returned or an exception thrown from the non-`finally` part of the method.  The fact that you're throwing a `RuntimeException` means that you *won't* be throwing the `IOException` that you otherwise would.  The compiler can work this out, and it therefore doesn't insist that you either declare or catch the `IOException`.

But the compiler only looks at one method at a time when it's performing this check.  So the second snippet fails to compile, because the compiler doesn't check whether `test()` will *always* throw the `RuntimeException`.  Instead, it assumes that `test()` might *not* throw the `RuntimeException`; and if that were to happen, the `IOException` would be thrown.  Therefore, the compiler insists that you either catch that `IOException`, or declare it in a `throws` clause.

Comment: Well, shouldn't Java compiler check for `throw` and `throws` keywords? and it's pretty clear that `test` method only throws an exception. I do agree that Java compiler doesn't care about **unchecked exceptions** but as far as I know the compiler is smart enough to figure out that we just throw an exception in `test` method, I'm not sure!

Comment: Yes, the compiler _does_ check for the `throws` keyword.  But there's no keyword that _promises_ that the method throws an exception.  All `throws` means is that the exception _might_ be thrown.  And in this particular code, it's the throwing of the `RuntimeException` that prevents the throwing of the `IOException`.

Comment: As I said, I totally understand the reason behind the first snippet. But the second one I still not sure and didn't get it why. I explicitly threw a runtime exception in the body of `test` method not only in the method declaration. The compiler checks the method block code, try to convert the return type to `int` and keep the function body as it is without returning anything. It still works because of `throw new RuntimeException()`!

Comment: The compiler builds one method at a time.  When it's building method 1, it doesn't look at the body of method 2; only at the signature.  So it doesn't know that the RuntimeException is _always_ thrown.  It only knows that it _might_ be thrown.  And that's not enough to guarantee that the IOException won't be thrown.  That's why you have to deal with the IOException.

Answer (score 0):

In java Exception handling have concept Exception propagation.

An exception is first thrown from the top of the stack and if it is not caught, it drops down the call stack to the previous method, if not caught there, the exception again drops down to the previous method, and so on until they are caught or until they reach the very bottom of the call stack. This is called exception propagation.

**Rule 1:** By default, Unchecked Exceptions are forwarded in calling chain (propagated).

**Rule 2:** By default, Checked Exceptions are not forwarded in calling chain (propagated).

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

In above code snippet it's the throwing of the RuntimeException that prevents the throwing of the IOException.

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
} catch(IOException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    test();
}
static final void test() throws RuntimeException {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

In above code snippet test() method throwing of the RuntimeException but not prevents the throwing of the IOException.
As by **Rule 2** by default compiler doesn't propagate the Checked Exceptions so for that you have to declare or handle the exception.

Lets take example if you replace **IOException** with **RuntimeException** then it will not give compiletime error because by **Rule 1** by default unchecked Exceptions are forwarded in calling chain (propagated).

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException();
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    test();
}
static final void test() throws RuntimeException{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```